# Exploding db data and echoing results based on assigned vars

Tags: php, arrays, explode

In the database table I have rows which have engineid
engine id's are 0 - 6 and if multiple engines are stored they are stored as 1:3:5 etc

I have the code below and I am trying to query the database and have it pull results. I then want it to query the engineid column, explode it at the : and then assign each of the values to another variable ( see code below )

```
    $itemsq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `crm`.`service-items` WHERE `itemgroup` = 'Service' LIMIT 0,10");
$items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq);
do {
$enginetype = explode(":",$items);
$eng0 = "engine_Sigma engine_K-Series engine_Duratec engine_Suzuki engine_Vauxhall engine_Crossflow";
$eng1 = "engine_Sigma";
$eng2 = "engine_K-Series";
$eng3 = "engine_Duratec";
$eng4 = "engine_Suzuki";
$eng5 = "engine_Vauxhall";
$eng6 = "engine_Crossflow";

$enginetype[0] = $eng0;
$enginetype[1] = $eng1;
$enginetype[2] = $eng2;
$enginetype[3] = $eng3;
$enginetype[4] = $eng4;
$enginetype[5] = $eng5;
$enginetype[6] = $eng6;

echo  "$items[code] - ".$enginetype;

} while($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq));
```

Hope that makes sense to you guys.
Please dont ask why I'm using : to separate data, its not my db and was like this when i started working here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show us an example of your db table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your engines in an array, not individual variables, and then pick out from the array the engine/s from the result.

```
<?php
$eng[] = "engine_Sigma engine_K-Series engine_Duratec engine_Suzuki engine_Vauxhall engine_Crossflow";
$eng[] = "engine_Sigma";
$eng[] = "engine_K-Series";
$eng[] = "engine_Duratec";
$eng[] = "engine_Suzuki";
$eng[] = "engine_Vauxhall";
$eng[] = "engine_Crossflow";

$items = '1:3:5';
$enginetype = explode(":", $items);

/*
engine_Sigma
engine_Duratec
engine_Vauxhall
*/
foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
    echo $eng[$key].PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/utBNG

Your code would look like:

```
<?php
// define engines - add a numeric key if you need it
$eng[] = "engine_Sigma engine_K-Series engine_Duratec engine_Suzuki engine_Vauxhall engine_Crossflow";
$eng[] = "engine_Sigma";
$eng[] = "engine_K-Series";
$eng[] = "engine_Duratec";
$eng[] = "engine_Suzuki";
$eng[] = "engine_Vauxhall";
$eng[] = "engine_Crossflow";

// query your db
$itemsq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `crm`.`service-items` WHERE `itemgroup` = 'Service' LIMIT 0,10");

// do/while? should prob just use a while loop
do {
    $enginetype = explode(":", $items);

    foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
        echo "\$eng[$key] - ".$eng[$key].PHP_EOL;
    }

} while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq));
```

Comment: Just testing the answer will reply back shortly , many thanks

Comment: also dont define `$eng` in the loop as it will not work.

Comment: np, glad to help

Comment: Doesnt work properly with the DB query ?
Getting undefined variable $items on Line 18
which is this line  $enginetype = explode(":", $items);

Comment: Whats the column name called? just needs adding to `explode(":", $items['column_name_for_1:3:5_value']);`

Comment: perfect ! just realised I was using wrong table name too :)

Comment: also i suggest you change it to a normal while loop, do/while may cause issues if it has no results.